# Changing the column name of a rails object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What if I want to refer to a column of an ActiveRecord object by a different name?  for example, I might call:

@posts = Posts.find(:all, :select => "created_on")

But instead of referring to @posts["created_on"], I'd like to refer to it as @posts["date"].  What would you recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
:select => "created_on AS date"
```

alternatively define a method

```
def date
  read_attribute(:created_on)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Already answered in your previous question, but here we go:

```
class Posts
  alias_method :date, :created_on
end
```

or simply

```
class Posts
  alias date created_on
end
```